# Linest function using java

Tags: java, excel

Is there any java third party library which can be used to implement Excel's LINEST function? I want to calculate LINEST value same as LINEST[known_y's;known_x's;cont;stats] function in Excel for an array of 'x' and 'y' values. Please let me know if anyone has an idea in implementing this.

Comment: Take a look at apache commons [SimpleRegression](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/regression/SimpleRegression.html) class.

Comment: [`LINEST`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LINEST-function-84d7d0d9-6e50-4101-977a-fa7abf772b6d) is listed as *calculates the statistics for a line by using the "least squares" method*, so you can implement it yourself, if you choose to accept this assignment, by implementing the [Linear least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29) algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ApacheCommons Math Library](http://commons.apache.org/math/). There are specific [SimpleRegression](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/regression/SimpleRegression.html) class.
Maybe help you!

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in right direction. It was simple indeed. I implemented this as below:                                                           double[][] input = {{1.8,30},{1.5,40},{1.3,50},{1.2,60},{1.1,70},{0.9,80},{0.6,90},{0.3,100}};                                                            SimpleRegression sr = new SimpleRegression();
sr.addData(input);
System.out.println(sr.getIntercept());

Answer (score 0):

From https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LINEST-function-84d7d0d9-6e50-4101-977a-fa7abf772b6d:
"The LINEST function calculates the statistics for a line by using the 'least squares' method to calculate a straight line that best fits your data" Looks like you just need to find an algorithm for for working out the least squares